# How to bypass isDebuggerPresent with x64dbg

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering

I found a guide how to bypass it in ollydbg:

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10332044/4784666)

But how to do that for an x64 application?

I have found following:

[image: isDebuggerPresent]

How must i manipulate this to don't get it detect the debugger?

Comment: Use the command `dbh`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the same way as described in the guide (i.e. by patching the code of IsDebuggerPresent).

Or you can set a breakpoint at the "movzx eax, byte ptr ds:[rax+2]" instruction, and when the program stops at the breakpoint, go to RAX+2 in the Dump pane and then change the byte from 1 to 0.

Comment: But when I just do following: replace this function with mov rax,  0   mov eax, 0   -> still detecting the debugger somewhere ...

Comment: !! I found usage of CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent in the code. must i care about it,too?

Comment: Yes, probably. There are many ways to check if the program is being debugged. Read e.g. this: http://antukh.com/blog/2015/01/19/malware-techniques-cheat-sheet/

Comment: So I Need to take care for all These possibly checks?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes. You can also try to use hiding plugins for x64dbg (TitanHide, ScyllaHide).